# Your preference to 'materializing' IEnumerables?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, memory, functional-programming

Sometimes it is necessary to actually 'evaluate' IEnumerable in the middle of a method, because it is used in multiple queries and compiler issues warning ("Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable")

```
var skippedIds = objects.Where(x => x.State=="skip")
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .Distinct();

            var skippedLookup = skippedIds.ToLookup(x => x.FundId, _ => new { _.Id, _.Name});

            if (skippedIds.Any()) // compiler warning
            {
                ...
                // other iterations over skippedIds, etc.
            }
```

I used to do:

```
var skippedIds = objects.Where(x => x.State=="skip")
                    .Select(x => x.Id)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
...
```

but would like to know if there are better options. The code above creates `List<T>` object on the heap which is I guess unnecessary GC burden in the context of a temporary variable that dies within the method.
I am now using `ToImmutableArray()` that comes with `System.Collections.Immutable` library. <strike>Not only this creates stack-allocated object</strike> (**not true, thanks commentors**), but it also attaches 'immutable' semantics to my code which is I guess a good functional-style practice.

But what are performance implications? What is the preferable way of 'materializing' temporary subquery results that are used in multiple places locally within a method?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: `ToImmutableArray` are orders of magnitude slower than the corresponding `ToList` method call so I would just go with `ToList` for simplicity.

Comment: @mjwills At it's heart, I don't think this is really a perf question. The "problem" is that the IDE (or it may be Resharper actually) is telling OP that they are possibly enumerating the enumerable multiple times.

Comment: @DavidG Which might be OK, but might also not be OK.

Comment: If you were really concerned about materializing the results, the issue is not about whether you're using `List` or `ImmutableArray` but materializing the results at all. You can fold something like `.Any()` inside a `foreach` that processes the results (and checking a flag that the loop sets). Worrying about GC vs. not GC is already a more advanced topic than most code needs to worry about. (And even worrying about what to materialize when is probably going too far if you haven't identified a bottleneck anywhere yet.)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Indeed. A poorly written EF query for example could hit the database twice unnecessarily. But in most situations, it's likely OK.

Comment: It is the fact that I am creating a mutable list that bothers me most. I am saying "please go ahead and change me", putting everything on the heap whereas my actual intent was just to eliminate multiple IEnumerable iterations. Thats why I switched to ImmutableArray, but not sure maybe there is a better collection out there that I am unaware of?

Comment: If the writable list troubles you so, assign it to a variable of type `IReadOnlyList`. Or in this specific instance remove `Any` and thus get rid of the need for `ToList` altogether.

Comment: a variable of type IReadOnlyList would mean I have to declare everything instead of just using 'var'

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen where does this "order of magnitude slower" comes from? I am not using `ImmutableList` which is indeed quite slow because of its internal tree implementation.

Comment: I did a simple conversion of a list to a list, and a list to an immutable array and benchmarked it. Results and code here: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/de70f3ab10b120961820de5fd1fd63b5 - **Feel free to poke a hole in my code and results though, there may be something I got wrong!** Note that I did not benchmark the usage of the resulting collections, I only benchmarked their creation.

Comment: You may wish to include those tests and the results in your question, so we can all learn from it.

Comment: I can change to use IEnumerable, no problem. And you're right, this changed drastically - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/66936cd630ff2e65d78fcac896c2b4a8 - so never mind my original comment, ToImmutableArray seems faster than ToList when ToList doesn't know the actual underlying size.

Comment: thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, I was feverishly putting together an example on gist, but i think it isnt necessary now )

Comment: @mjwills just wanted to know opinions & what people are using out there, glad that my choice of collection isnt that bad

Comment: What makes you think that `ImmutableArray` stores the data on the stack?  How could it, even if it wanted to?  It stores the data in the heap, just like a list.  Worse, in fact, since it loses all memory locality by spreading out the information, and having more overhead per item in the collection, rather than having a single contiguous block of memory with a fixed overhead for the whole collection.

Comment: @Servy what sources are you using for statement "having more overhead per item in the collection"? from what I know about ImmutableArray internals, theres no such overhead. You are right however about heap allocation, it is indeed stored on heap despite being value type...

Comment: Well, the `struct` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn638264(v=vs.111).aspx) is on the stack but its underlying array (just like the array underlying a `List`) is on the heap. As you'd expect. Perf-wise, @AlexeiS is correct - there is no loss of memory-locality since arrays are contiguous.

Answer (score 5):

The performance implications of materialising it in memory are:

- The initial grab of all items from the database - if you're not going to be using all of the items, then you could be taking more than you need.
- Depending on the structure you use you could have insertion costs - `ToImmutableArray()` will be about as quick as `ToArray()` because `ImmutableArray` just wraps the built-in array type and removes the mutation option.
- GC burdens are less of a concern if you're throwing the object away quickly.  Because it's very unlikely the item will jump from `Gen 0` to `Gen 1` and will be collected without much cost.  But obviously the more big objects you allocate the more likely it is that a collection is triggered.

You could use the `Seq<A>` type from [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) (Disclosure: I'm the author).  Which is designed to be a 'better enumerable' in that it will only ever consume each item in an `IEnumerable<A>` once and is lazy like `IEnumerable<A>`.

So, you could do this:

```
var skippedIds = objects.Where(x => x.State=="skip")
                        .Select(x => x.Id)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToSeq();
```

Obviously there's nothing for free in this world, and the costs of `Seq<A>` are:

- An allocation per item consumed (as it memorises the items you've read so you don't do it again).  But they're tiny objects that just have two references in and so cause very little GC pressure.
- Holding open the connection to the database longer than you possibly need, which could cause other performance issues with your db: deadlocks, etc.

But the benefits are you only consume what you need and you consume it once.  Personally I would look to limit your query and use `ToImmutableArray()`, taking less than you need from the db will always be the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the issue is that you **have** materialised the results (in the form of a `Lookup`), but then refer to the *unmaterialised* results.

```
var skippedIds = objects.Where(x => x.State=="skip")
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .Distinct();

var skippedLookup = skippedIds.ToLookup(x => x.FundId, _ => new { _.Id, _.Name});

if (skippedIds.Any()) // compiler warning
```

In the above code, `skippedIds` is not materialised, but `skippedLookup` is. As such, you may consider changing:

```
if (skippedIds.Any()) // compiler warning
```

to:

```
if (skippedLookup.Any()) // no compiler warning
```

If we take the more general case, some additional guidance:

- Consider the performance cost of multiple enumeration (e.g. hitting the database twice) vs materialising (e.g. RAM usage) - which is best can be contextual
- Consider using `ToList` or `ToImmutableArray` for materialising (both appear to perform well).
- Consider whether any of the LINQ operations can be removed from the code without an impact on overall functionality. A common mistake is to use `Any` then `foreach` - in many cases the `Any` can be removed since the `foreach` will *automatically* do nothing if the enumerable is empty.
- If the `IEnumerable` is using LINQ to Objects and you are performing `Distinct` then a materialising operation (e.g. `ToList`) then instead use [`new HashSet<YourTypeHere>(YourEnumerableHere)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx) . It will perform the `Distinct` and the materialising operation in one hit.
- When materialising using `ToList` consider exposing the resulting `List` as `IReadOnlyList` to indicate to the consumers that it is not designed to be altered.
- In practical terms, it rarely matters much what approach you choose. There will some GC overhead of the `List` and its underlying array, sure. But in the broader context of the overall GC load (e.g. of the objects that the `List` contains) it is unlikely to be an issue. If the list gets big enough then the Large Object Heap can be involved, which isn't optimal. But honestly, let the GC do its job. If there is a problem, optimise then but not before.